# How do I mount multiple rails engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, bots, rails-engines

What should I do if I want to be able to host multiple instances of the same rails engine (bot)?  This will be separate engines (using the same code) but using different model attributes, data, etc..

The only way that makes sense to me is to mount separate engine (bots) doing something like this..

`mount SomeENGINE, at: 'bot/:unique_id'`

Is this the way to do it?  Basically having a separate web-hook per engine as a way to identify each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah your idea will basically work.  Here's an example for mounting the enginge 10 times at 10 different routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  (1..10).each do |idx|
    mount MyEngine::Engine => "/bot_#{idx}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this dynamically? For example based on model IDs? That way a new engine is mounted when a model is created?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to. According to the documentation on `mount` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/Mapper/Base.html#method-i-mount) it accepts the same options as `match`, which does permit wildcard parameters.

Comment: I'm trying something like this but no luck ->  mount MyEngine::Engine, at: 'bot', path: 'bot/:id'

Comment: check your `rake routes` to make sure the generated route looks correct